# Ubuntu 16.04, root command sh took 400% cpus usage even after fresh reboot

Tags: 16.04, command-line, cpu

I recently found out my Ubuntu has a process (shows in images) always took about 400% cpu usage for nothing. It is always there even I rebooted my PC and nothing has been done yet. I tried to kill it, but it regenerates in few seconds.

Screenshot from `top` – the first row, PID 4313, root, command `sh`:

[image: screenshot from top]

I have searched for the similar problem but none of them is caused by this "root sh command".  Anyone know why is it here and I can't get rid of it?

Any ideas will be a great help. Thanks!

***Update***:
Thanks @dessert.  I think use screenshot in this case makes more sense.  And I don't know how to paste the text from htop actually..

[image: screenshot from htop]
I'm actually new to everything here.  htop looks a very handy tool to investigate the processes.  It is ntpd that root is running.  I found a similar issue from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275453/macos-ntpd-uses-more-than-100-of-cpu) for macOS by changing the **Date & Time** to automatic.  But it doesn't work in my case.  I feel it must be something simple to fix. But I just don't know how....

**Update:**

Solved the problem.  I think it is some kind of bitcoin mining attack.
While the 'ntpd' was eating the cpu usage, I realized I didn't even have the ntpd installed...

```
which ntpd #returns nothing.
```

When I took a look at the strace -p, it gave me this:

[image: screenshot of strace -p]

There were 8 subprocesses.  I don't know much about ntpd, but this looks unusual and suspicious..

Then I used following command to locate the executing files:

```
cd /proc/14503
sudo ls -l exe
```

[image]

Go to /cpu/bin folder, and I found the files faking 'ntpd' process.  There was a cron.d file I think was used to regenerating process.

Delete the whole 'bin' folder, kill the process.  The cpu usage was ceased and didn't come back again.

```
sudo rm -rv bin
sudo kill 14503
```

I didn't reboot my OS to verify whether it will be regenerated.  But I will at least change my root passwd right away.. I don't know whether this means someone has my root passwd already.  If yes, how and why could him have the pw?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Try to view process tree with dependencies using `htop` and add its screenshot to the question. This `sh` process was called by some parent, but we can not determine it from your current screenshots.